# Xetex does not use any of my installed fonts in Beamer document

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex, ubuntu

I recently upgraded to Xubuntu 14.04 which has texlive 2013 in the repositories.

Before, I used Ubuntu 12.04 with texlive 2012.

Everything works except that when I compile my XeTeX documents they come out with the LM-Modern font. No matter what font I choose with `\setmainfont`. I have not deleted any fonts from my systems home directory and e.g. Libreoffice sees all fonts. I already run `texhash` in terminal but this had no effect.
Could somebody help me? I urgently need to compile a document that should look nice.

Comment: Can you show the output of `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{fontspec}  \setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}  \begin{document}  foo  \end{document}`

Comment: Have you run `fc-cache` to update the FontConfig Cache? See also the section "Fonts" in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/10995

Comment: I had run fc-cache before, but that did not change anything. I now could narrow down the problem a little bit: If I test a document like Herbert suggested in his comment, everything works and I can select all fonts installed on my system. The problem occurs only with the beamer package. If I use the dummy document that Herbert suggested and change only the document class into <code>\documentclass{beamer}</code>, the only output I get is LM-Modern/the standard latex font.

Comment: I just tested it. The same thing happens on my Mac with the current MacTeX distribution installed as well.

Comment: Ok. I found out that with beamer I have to add \let\sfdefault\rmdefault to make it work. But why? And why was this not necessary with texlive 2012?

Comment: Did you not have `\usefonttheme{serif}` in your document?  With that, you shouldn’t need to redefine `\sfdefault`.  See §18.1 of the `beamer` documentation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments